# jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js +like count is giving 'undefined people' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js     plugin to show the fb wall post on my site.
But now it is giving me 'undefined people like this' text instead of like count

What can be the issue, Does I need to upadte any thing for as per new changes from facebook.

Please let me know.

Comment: @neosmart Can u please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

Got the solution from forum. Thanx

Please check this:

https://neosmart-stream.de/forums/topic/undefined-people-like-this-2/